# How to fix distortion on image and text when using CSS scale?

Tags: html, css

Creating a card row in which each card will scale by 1.05x when hovered over it. Everything about the scaling works fine and is smooth, but one thing that really bugs me is how the image and text goes out of focus while scaling, and then regains  focus once its been scaled. It's difficult to demonstrate but I've tried it in Chrome, Firefox and Edge in case it was a browser problem (somehow its even worse in edge) but I was wondering if there was a way to fix this as it really destroys the look.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 article">
            <a href="">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/xchurch.jpg" alt="Card image">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some example text.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.article {
  transition: .5s;
}
.article a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.article a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.article:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a few ways to fix this. The best way to deal with the distortion during scaling is with the following. However, it leaves some distortion after scaling.

```css
.article {
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.article a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.article a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.article:hover {
  transform: perspective(1px) scale(1.05);
}
```

If you really cannot have any distortion, you can imitate the scaling by changing properties individually. I built a simple workaround for this scenario, but you might want to refine it to fit your needs.

```css
.article {
  transition: .5s;
  margin: 10px 0 0 5px;
}
.article:hover {
  max-width: calc(25% + 10px);
  margin: 0;
}
.article a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.article:hover a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.article h4, .article p {
  transition: .5s;
}
.article:hover h4 {
  font-size: 1.61rem;
}
.article:hover p {
  font-size: 1.07rem;
}
```

Hope these help you.